# t-sql update XML element value based on another element value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xml-dml

Using SQL Server 2012, if I have the following value in one row of an XML type column:

```
<ArrayOfScheduledJobParameters xmlns="http://schemas.data.org/ScheduledJobServiceLibrary">
  <ScheduledJobParameters>
    <Key>OutputFileName</Key>
    <Value>CPVR{0}.txt</Value>
  </ScheduledJobParameters>
  <ScheduledJobParameters>
    <Key>DaysBeforeExpiration</Key>
    <Value>60</Value>
  </ScheduledJobParameters>
  <ScheduledJobParameters>
    <Key>MaxItemsByReportServiceCall</Key>
    <Value>100</Value>
  </ScheduledJobParameters>
</ArrayOfScheduledJobParameters>
```

I want to change the value of the element `<Value>` based on the value contained in the element `<Key>`.  Specifically I want to be able to set `<Value>` to 150 where the element `<Key>` contains the value 'MaxItemsByReportServiceCall'.  All that I have been able to do is update the first node of `<ScheduledJobParameters>`.  I can't find how to do it, if it's even possible in any of the documentation I read on XML DML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function [`modify()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093(v=sql.110).aspx) and correct XQuery to set the value that you need. The syntax is quite tricky though:

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET ColumnName.modify('declare namespace NS="http://schemas.data.org/ScheduledJobServiceLibrary";replace value of (/NS:ArrayOfScheduledJobParameters/NS:ScheduledJobParameters[NS:Key="MaxItemsByReportServiceCall"]/NS:Value/text())[1] with "150"')
WHERE <your conditions to select rows>
```

In `modify()` function you first declare your namespace. Then you use `replace value of` and correct XQUery. For XQuery you find the `ScheduledJobParameters` element that has child element name with value `MaxItemsByReportServiceCall` and select the text of its child element value. Then you use `with "new value"` to update the field.

Comment: @dotnettom I just joined so I cannot vote up yet (need 15 reputation) but I just want to say thank you and agreed that the syntax is not intuitive at all.